# how do I prevent blazor wasm from redirecting a get

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm app.

I have a third party component that is probing to see if a file exists or not on the server. So it does a get on `http://xxxxx/dir/D`. The problem is that some part of the blazor plumbing converts this into a request to reload `index.html` and try to route to a page called `dir/D` (I have no control over this name, I know it works fine if the URL were `xxxxx/dir/D.f`, but its not)

I want 404 , not index.html

I am sure I saw the code that controls this behavior in blazor wasm app but I cant find it again.

Comment: How is this hosted?

Comment: In vs2022 dev env

Comment: But is asp.net hosted or a static app?  And what part of the URL do you control?  The /dir/ part?

Comment: works the same from passive app host - ie pure static (github pages). Works the same with xxx/foo